# How to check if a component is mounted in React-Native ES6

Tags: react-native

I am setting a listener in my application and using force update whenever it is broadcasted but it gives error forceUpdate cant be called on unmounted component. How can I check if a component is mounted now that the `isMounted()` function is deprecated.

```js
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
import ExpAndroid from './ExpAndroid';
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Component,
  AsyncStorage,
  Navigator,
  DeviceEventEmitter
} = React;

var rowID;
var img=require('./resource/ic_pause_white.png');





class Example1 extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }
  componentWillMount(){

      rowID = this.props.rowIdentity;
      console.log("rowID "+rowID);

  }


componentDidMount(){
  console.log('component  mounted')
  this.start();

  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('playMusicStatus', (data)=> {


   if(data.playMusic==true){

     img=require('./resource/ic_pause_white.png');
       rowID++;
        this.setState(this.state);
        ExpAndroid.someMethod1("someurl);


  }



});
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  console.log('componentwill  unmounted')
}

  start() {

    var  url = "some url";
    ToastAndroid.prepareToPlay(url,true);
}



render() {




     return (
      <Image source={require('./resource/album_back.png')} style={styles.background}>
      <Image
      source={{uri:this.state.trackDetails[rowID].thumnail_loc}}
      style={styles.thumbnail}
      />
      <View style={styles.flowRow}>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >text1 + {rowID}: </Text>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >{this.state.details[rowID].text1}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.flowRow}>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >text2 : </Text>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >{this.state.details[rowID].text2}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.flowRow}>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >Text3 : </Text>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >{this.state.Details[rowID].Text3}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.flowRow}>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >Text4 : </Text>
      <Text
      style={styles.titles}
      >{this.state.details[rowID].Text4}</Text>
      </View>


      </Image>
    );
  }
}
var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,

  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,

    width: null,
    height: null,
  },

  flowRow : {
    flexDirection :'row',

  },
  flowRowPlay : {
    flexDirection :'row',
    alignSelf:'center',

  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
  },

  thumbnail: {
    width: 100,
    height: 120,
    alignSelf:'center',
    margin :30
  },

  controls: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    margin:20
  },


  titles: {
    fontSize: 15,
    margin:20,
    color: 'white',

  },
  timings: {
    fontSize: 12,
    margin:5,
    color: 'white',

  },
});

module.exports = Example1;
```

Answer (score 60):

You can handle this yourself in your component:

```js
componentDidMount() { 
  this._mounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._mounted = false;
}
```

Then you can check the value of `this._mounted` in your listener.

Please note that using `forceUpdate()` should be avoided https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: In my case componentWillUnmount() is not called . I have registered my event at native side and listening to it in react in componentDidMount.And whenever it receives that listener it calls the setstate to update the view.

Comment: If `componentWillUnmount` why would you need to know if it's unmounted?

Comment: I have updated the code,everytime I receive the listener I update the rowId by 1 and call setState on it,but in my case it gives me error cannot update the unmounted state and by the time row id gets incremented by 2 or 3 and then state is set.

Comment: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

Comment: how should we avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was changing the callback in componentWillMount.

```js
let asyncCallback;

componentDidMount(){
    asyncCallback = res=> this.setState({data: res});
    asyncTask(asyncCallback);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    asyncCallback = ()=> console.log("AsyncCallback called but component has unmounted");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ReactUpdateQueue`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d47a3a36ee9de36cf32cd9233f923ced07b5d79d/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactUpdateQueue.js#L88-L113), you can avoid managing your own `isMounted` state.

```js
const ReactUpdateQueue = require('ReactUpdateQueue');

// Pass the ref to your component.
if (ReactUpdateQueue.isMounted(view)) {
  // Your component is mounted!
}
```

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen This solution broke when React started using Fiber.

Comment: Yes, it's an antipattern now - [isMounted antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)